# curl ignoring --connect-timeout parameter

Tags: jenkins, curl

I am running the following curl command from a Windows batch (in a Jenkins job, for what it's worth):

```
C:\>curl --connect-timeout 240 --user <myuser> --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data @C:\dataOut\myData.xml http://www.myURL.it/myApi.asmx -o C:\dataIn\mtResponse.xml --verbose
```

When the server is fast enough everything goes right, but occasionally the reply is slow and the connection times out.

I thought that the `--connect-timeout 240` parameter would have set the conection timeout to 240 seconds (i.e. 4 minutes), nonetheless the connection seems to timeout after 20 seconds:

```
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:20 --:--:--     0* connect to N.N.N.N port 80 failed: Timed out
```

The complete output is the following:

```
C:\>curl --connect-timeout 240 --user <myuser> --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data @C:\dataOut\myData.xml http://www.myURL.it/myApi.asmx -o C:\dataIn\mtResponse.xml --verbose 
29/06/2020 16:33:06   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
29/06/2020 16:33:06                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
29/06/2020 16:33:06 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying N.N.N.N...
29/06/2020 16:33:07 * TCP_NODELAY set
29/06/2020 16:33:07 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:12 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:13 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:14 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:15 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:16 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:17 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:18 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:20 --:--:--     0* connect to N.N.N.N port 80 failed: Timed out
29/06/2020 16:33:27 * Failed to connect to www.myURL.it port 80: Timed out
29/06/2020 16:33:27 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:21 --:--:--     0
29/06/2020 16:33:27 * Closing connection 0
29/06/2020 16:33:27 curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.myURL.it port 80: Timed out
29/06/2020 16:33:27
```

And my curl version is the following:

```
C:\>curl --version
curl 7.64.1 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.64.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1b (Schannel) zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 WinIDN libssh2/1.8.2 nghttp2/1.37.0
Release-Date: 2019-03-27
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile MultiSSL NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI TLS-SRP brotli libz
```

What am I missing to keep curl waiting for server for at least 240 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try reading the `curl` documentation? It is full of interesting things.

For instance, big surprise, the "connect timeout" is about CONNECTING to the server i.e. checking that it is alive. It does not care about the time it takes for the server to give its full RESPONSE.

Since the full documentation is quite long, just zoom on a tutorial about timeouts:
https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-timeouts

> Never spend more than this to connect
> `curl --connect-timeout 2.37`

> Maximum time allowed to spend
> `curl --max-time 5.5`

> Transfer speeds slower than this means exit *(alternative to a fixed time-out)*
> `curl --speed-time 15 --speed-limit 1000`

Comment: Yes I did check the documentation but since all indicators ( % Total,    % Received, % Xferd,  Average Speed, ...) in the console output were set to zero all the time, I assumed the connection was not yet set up at the time of the timeout... Also the error is « Failed to **CONNECT** to www.myURL.it port 80: Timed out » and not something like « **DATA TRANSFER**  aborted: Timed out ». I'll try again calling `curl --connect-timeout 240 --max-time 300`, thanks

Comment: The web server (front-end) has nothing to transmit until the back-end has finished processing. In worst-case scenarios the back-end is zombie but the front-end continues accepting connections and keeping them alive indefinitely; if you set up a canary test for server liveness, you have to set a time-out on client side (I've been there...)

Comment: Also, if you download a file through a Corporate proxy, the proxy usually has to first download the file entirely on temp storage, run a malware scan on it, then at last start transmitting the file to you. Could take quite a while before you see the 1st bytes coming through. You have to set the time-outs accordingly _(even when running `yum` or `apt-get` commands against an Artifactory instance -- if the package is not in the cache it must be downloaded through the proxy, etc)_

Comment: What I am expecting back is just a SOAP envelope carrying a 4-digit integer and a boolean encoded by the strings "false" or "true".
Nonetheless the XML overhead the whole response.xml file is as small as 384 bytes (not kbytes, just bytes). The normal round-trip time is about 3 seconds from the curl command execution to the response received. I don't think that the response is scanned for malware since the communications is between two machines both inside the company's intranet.

Comment: Anyway, `--max-time 300` should do the trick, I hope! Thanks (But I have to wait for a server response time longer than 20 seconds to verify it, and this happens only occasionally - anyway I will check the logs looking for instances of this job lasted more than 20 seconds)

Comment: Unfortunately, also running `curl --connect-timeout 240 --max-time 300` i had a **connection timeout** after exactly **20 seconds** `0:00:20 --:--:--     0* connect to X.X.X.X port 8092 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to myUrl port 8092: Timed out` so, I'm afraid that `--max-time` was not what I was looking for, after all...

Comment: Hmm... looks like there are some specific builds of `curl` that are screwed, cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571246/curl-max-time-and-connect-timeout-not-working-at-all >> try another version from another repo, just in case